The plugin "externalize-deps" was triggered by this import , Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
I got problem after build react in inertia with laravel using vite, so the build run smoothly but when i ran it in browser got problem The plugin "externalize-deps" was triggered by this import Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
also here's my config
vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'
import babel from 'vite-plugin-babel'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.tsx',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
        legacy({
            targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
            additionalLegacyPolyfills: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
        }),
        babel({
            babelConfig: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
            }
        }),
        replace({
            'Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });':
                'Object.defineProperty(exports || {}, "__esModule", { value: true });',
            delimiters: ['\n', '\n'],
            preventAssignment: true,
        }),
    ],
});

package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "vite build",
        "dev": "vite"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^2.0.0",
        "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@types/node": "^18.19.57",
        "@types/react": "^18.3.11",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
        "@types/react-speech-recognition": "^3.9.5",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.7.4",
        "concurrently": "^9.0.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
        "nanoid": "^5.0.7",
        "postcss": "^8.4.31",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "vite": "^5.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.25.7",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.25.7",
        "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^6.0.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^5.4.2",
        "openai": "^4.68.1",
        "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
        "react-countdown": "^2.3.6",
        "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
        "react-responsive-modal": "^6.4.2",
        "react-speech-recognition": "^3.10.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.1",
        "rodal": "^2.1.0",
        "vite-plugin-babel": "^1.2.0",
        "vite-plugin-symfony": "^7.0.4"
    }
}

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "rootDir": "./resources/js",
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./resources/js/*"
            ]
        },
        "types": [
            "vite/client"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./resources/js/**/*"
    ]
}

Okay so removing "type": "module", from package.json maybe work but i got another problem from other library :
"laravel-vite-plugin" resolved to an ESM file.
so the fix is the package json need "type": "module", which is contradiction with my previous fix, please help :(
